# Alternative for remove() when using strict mode, filter using one element and hiding all other

Tags: javascript, angularjs, performance, javascript-objects

I am trying to remove all the items from a list except "**Red**" on a specific condition by using remove(), but when I debug, it gives error:

**"Accessing the 'arguments' property of a function is not allowed in strict mode"**.

Is there a alternative for remove that I can use in this situation. Below is the code that I am using:

```
for (var k = 0; k < homeCtrl.List.length; k++) {
      if (homeCtrl.ColorList[k].name != 'Red') {
            homeCtrl.ColorList.remove[k];
      }
}
```

Comment: Please try searching before asking questions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you want to remove items from an `array`, you can simply use [**`Array.prototype.filter()`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter):

```js
var array = [  
   {  
      "id":1,
      "name":"Red"
   },
   {  
      "id":2,
      "name":"Blue"
   },
   {  
      "id":3,
      "name":"Red"
   },
   {  
      "id":4,
      "name":"Green"
   },
   {  
      "id":5,
      "name":"Red"
   }
];

var withoutRed = array.filter(function(value) {
  return value.name != "Red";
});

console.log(withoutRed);
```

Comment: thank you for this suggestion this works perfect but in my case splice is a better option.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `splice()`

```
for (var k = 0; k < homeCtrl.List.length; k++) {
    if (homeCtrl.ColorList[k].name != 'Red') {
        homeCtrl.ColorList.splice(k, 1);
    }
}
```

See a dummy example below:

```js
var app = angular.module("sa", []);

app.controller("FooController", function($scope) {

  var homeCtrl = this;
  homeCtrl.List = [{
    name: 'Yello'
  }, {
    name: 'Red'
  }, {
    name: 'green'
  }];
  
  homeCtrl.ColorList = angular.copy(homeCtrl.List);

  homeCtrl.remove = function() {
    for (var k = 0; k < homeCtrl.List.length; k++) {
      if (homeCtrl.ColorList[k] && homeCtrl.ColorList[k].name != 'Red') {
        homeCtrl.ColorList.splice(k, 1);
      }
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="sa" ng-controller="FooController as fooCtrl">
  
  {{fooCtrl.ColorList}}
  <br><br>
  <a ng-click="fooCtrl.remove()" href="">Clear</a>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you Shashank this is working beautifully.

Comment: Glad this worked!! Feel free to accept the answer

Answer (score -2):

It looks like you're coming across issues here because you're modifying the list that you're iterating over. Javascript doesn't like this. Try creating a new list instead, and then replacing the old one.

```
var myNewList = [];
for (var k = 0; k < homeCtrl.List.length; k++) {
                    if (homeCtrl.List[k].name === 'Red') {
                        myNewList.push(homeCtrl.List[k]);
                    }
// now myNewList only contains the 'Red' elements.
```

Comment: developer033's suggestion to use .filter is more elegant than keeping the loop.